# How to secure firebase cloud function

Tags: http, google-cloud-functions

I have an http function, that uses nodemailer and gmail to send emails when invoked,

I use it for a contact us form on my website,

I find that I'm able to send as many as I can from Postman, and similarly can just set up a script that keeps on firing that function without limits

I've looked everywhere to find a way to restrict access, but couldn't find anything that made sense as a simple straightforward solution

Comment: You will have to figure how you want users to identify themselves, pass their credentials, and validate them.  This is the case for securing any public API, not just Cloud Functions.  A full discussion is rather broad for Stack Overflow, but these are the things you'll have to think about and implement.  It is not just a matter of configuration - it's going to require engineering effort.

Comment: Sounds good, how about if I want guests to be able to invoke this function, as It's just a contact form, could you please give a hint on how to identify my guests and validate that they're my website's guests and not some random guy running a script elsewhere, Many thanks

Comment: I doubt there's going to be enough difference between "some random guy running your scripts" and a legitimate user running those same scripts in their browser because they visit your web site. But for the access controls you can place on Cloud Functions, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing

Comment: Practically speaking, from the perspective of an API endpoint, there is no difference between a guest at a web site, and some random guy running a script.  You will need some way to identify the user, as I originally suggested.  You will need to use some form of authentication.